# What is the rationale behind the node architecture (Runtime + Host)

Tags: polkadot, runtime, nodes, architecture

Is the separation of the Runtime business logic from the host intended solely for enabling forkless upgrades, or does it also aim to facilitate compatibility with different hosts?